# Send broadcast message to all connected client using php socket

Tags: php, sockets, php-socket

I am making server application where i need to broadcast message to all my connected users. I have create three files as below.

1) socketServer.php (Working Fine) 
2) index.html (Working Fine) 
**3) notification.php (Issue in this file)**

notification.php (Creating Problem)

```
<?php 
$post_data = json_encode(array('message'=>'Please refresh your page.'));
$socket = fsockopen("192.168.10.107", 9000, $errno, $errstr, 15);
if(!$socket){
    echo ' error: ' . $errno . ' ' . $errstr;
    die;
}else{
    $http  = "POST /myapp/socketTrigger.php HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $http .= "Host: 192.168.10.107\r\n";
    $http .= "User-Agent: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\r\n";
    $http .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $http .= "Content-length: " . strlen($post_data) . "\r\n";
    $http .= "Sec-WebSocket-Key: gjdsjh8^8==Hjhdsur\r\n"; 
    $http .= $post_data . "\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($socket, $http);     
    $contents = "";
    while (!feof($socket)) {
        $contents .= fgets($socket, 1024);
    }
    fclose($socket);
}
?>
```

- Please check notification.php file and let me know what's wrong doing here i am. It create infinite loop.
- I want to broadcast message to all connected users using notification.php file.

**UPDATE**

**socketTrigger.php**

```
<?php
// $host = '192.168.10.70'; //host
$host = '192.168.10.107'; //host
$port = '9000'; //port
$null = NULL; //null var

//Create TCP/IP sream socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
//reuseable port
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);

//bind socket to specified host
socket_bind($socket, 0, $port);

//listen to port
socket_listen($socket);

//create & add listning socket to the list
$clients = array($socket);

//start endless loop, so that our script doesn't stop
while (true) {
    //manage multipal connections
    $changed = $clients;
    //returns the socket resources in $changed array
    socket_select($changed, $null, $null, 0, 10);

    //check for new socket
    if (in_array($socket, $changed)) {
        $socket_new = socket_accept($socket); //accpet new socket
        $clients[] = $socket_new; //add socket to client array

        $header = socket_read($socket_new, 1024); //read data sent by the socket

        perform_handshaking($header, $socket_new, $host, $port); //perform websocket handshake

        socket_getpeername($socket_new, $ip); //get ip address of connected socket
        $response = mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'system', 'message'=>$ip.' connected'))); //prepare json data
        send_message($response); //notify all users about new connection

        //make room for new socket
        $found_socket = array_search($socket, $changed);
        unset($changed[$found_socket]);
    }

    //loop through all connected sockets
    foreach ($changed as $changed_socket) { 

        //check for any incomming data
        while(socket_recv($changed_socket, $buf, 1024, 0) >= 1)
        {
            $received_text = unmask($buf); //unmask data
            // break;
            $tst_msg = json_decode($received_text); //json decode 

            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($tst_msg);
            echo "\r\n\r\n";

            //$user_name = $tst_msg->name; //sender name
            $user_message = $tst_msg->message; //message text
            //$user_color = $tst_msg->color; //color

            //prepare data to be sent to client
            if(!empty($user_message))
            {
                $response_text = mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'usermsg', 'message'=>$user_message)));
                send_message($response_text); //send data
            }
            break 2; //exist this loop
        }

        $buf = @socket_read($changed_socket, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ);
        if ($buf === false) { // check disconnected client
            // remove client for $clients array
            $found_socket = array_search($changed_socket, $clients);
            socket_getpeername($changed_socket, $ip);
            unset($clients[$found_socket]);

            //notify all users about disconnected connection
            $response = mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'system', 'message'=>$ip.' disconnected')));
            send_message($response);
        }
    }
}
// close the listening socket
socket_close($socket);

function send_message($msg)
{
    global $clients;
    foreach($clients as $changed_socket)
    {
        @socket_write($changed_socket,$msg,strlen($msg));
    }
    return true;
}


//Unmask incoming framed message
function unmask($text) {
    $length = ord($text[1]) & 127;
    if($length == 126) {
        $masks = substr($text, 4, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 8);
    }
    elseif($length == 127) {
        $masks = substr($text, 10, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 14);
    }
    else {
        $masks = substr($text, 2, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 6);
    }
    $text = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {
        $text .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i%4];
    }
    return $text;
}

//Encode message for transfer to client.
function mask($text)
{
    $b1 = 0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f);
    $length = strlen($text);

    if($length <= 125)
        $header = pack('CC', $b1, $length);
    elseif($length > 125 && $length < 65536)
        $header = pack('CCn', $b1, 126, $length);
    elseif($length >= 65536)
        $header = pack('CCNN', $b1, 127, $length);
    return $header.$text;
}

//handshake new client.
function perform_handshaking($receved_header,$client_conn, $host, $port)
{
    $headers = array();
    $lines = preg_split("/\r\n/", $receved_header);
    foreach($lines as $line)
    {
        $line = chop($line);
        if(preg_match('/\A(\S+): (.*)\z/', $line, $matches))
        {
            $headers[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
        }
    }

    if(isset($headers['Sec-WebSocket-Key'])) {
        $secKey = $headers['Sec-WebSocket-Key'];
        $secAccept = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($secKey . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')));
        //hand shaking header
        $upgrade  = "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n" .
        "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" .
        "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
        "WebSocket-Origin: $host\r\n" .
        "WebSocket-Location: ws://$host:$port/myapp/shout.php\r\n".
        "Sec-WebSocket-Accept:$secAccept\r\n\r\n";
        socket_write($client_conn,$upgrade,strlen($upgrade));
    }
}
?>
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Notification</title>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="notification">
    </div>
</body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(){
    //create a new WebSocket object.
    var wsUri = "ws://192.168.10.107:9000/myapp/socketTrigger.php";
    // var wsUri = "ws://192.168.10.70:9000/myapp/server.php";
    websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
    websocket.onopen = function(ev) { // connection is open 
        $('#notification').append("<div class=\"system_msg\">Connection Status :: You are Connected!</div>"); //notify user
    }

    //#### Message received from server?
    websocket.onmessage = function(ev) {
        var msg = JSON.parse(ev.data); //PHP sends Json data

        console.log(msg);

        if(msg.type == 'usermsg' && msg.message != "")
        {
            $('#notification').append("<div class=\"user_msg\">"+msg.message+"</div>"); //notify user
        }
    };

    websocket.onerror   = function(ev){$('#notification').append("<div class=\"system_error\">Error Occurred - "+ev.data+"</div>");}; 
    websocket.onclose   = function(ev){$('#notification').append("<div class=\"system_msg\">Connection Closed</div>");}; 
});

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: 1) You're sending malformed headers. 2) The clients are connected to `socketServer.php`, you can't access them from `notification.php`. However you could connect to `socketServer.php` and ask it to pass the message.

Comment: @t.m.adam, I am using jquery websocket library in index.html to get response from server and in socketServer.php, i use socket code for PHP. Please check i have added both files here

Answer (score 0):

Your solution isn't correct and logical. You most create message table for your users and when you want to send broadcast msg, only create a new record on messages table and in client side, client phone or web application most check this table e.g each 10 second